# Why does empty string literal evaluate to false in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why does `""` evaluate to `false`?

For example

```
if ("") {
    console.log("I naïvely expected this to run");
} 
else {
    console.log("but this runs instead")
}
```

Comment: Because the spec says so.

Comment: In the ECMAScript specification, the [`if` statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5) passes its operand to the abstract operation [`ToBoolean`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2), which is specified to yield `false` for zero-length strings.

Comment: I expected it evaluate to true because there is a something there, granted it's a literal not an object. Interestingly if the String is an object it works the other way around.

Comment: @alexbirkett This is because `new String` is an object, which, according to the specification of [`ToBoolean`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2), is coerced to `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in Javascript there are true-like and false-like values. Empty string, null , undefined,NaN and 0 are all false-like .

Comment: As well as `0` and `NaN`

Comment: Yes , thank you for adding the extra info for the others :P